# Send html from server to ajax call in IE9

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer-9

Hi I want to send html response back to ajax call and all works great beside IE9 and lower

The problem is

when I send this from the server

```
$response = array("<p>hello</p>");
echo json_encode($response);
```

the ajax call recive this

```
["<p>hello&lt;\/p&gt;"]</p>
```

with error message:

> script1014 invalid character

it adds extra closing p tag at the end. In others browsers it works fine

IE10 example:

```
["<p>hello<\/p>"]
```

Note: I am using jQuery Form Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

you should say that you are echoing html out put to the html header in json encode.. ok add this line in front of your final echo  - header('content-type: application/json');

```
header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

not tested hope it would fix your error

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this alert download window to download entire file.

Comment: It will only download the file if you attempt to navigate a frame directly to the target URL. If you request it with an XHR object or SCRIPT tag, the JSON will be used silently by the browser.

Comment: Could you please give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what Ram says is correct.

In Internet Explorer, it often downloads files instead of viewing them inside the browser. If you were to test the code in say Firefox or Chrome, they would display the JSON as the proper results.

This code *does* work:

```
<?php
$response = array("<p>hello</p>");
header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```